# firebase onSnapshot gets update before create is complete

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "post" that listens to changes on its comments in `react` like so:

```js
// React hook state 
const [comments, setComments] = useState([])

// My listener in useEffect
db.collection(`users/${userId}/posts/${postId}/comments`)
   .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      let newComments = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        newComments.push({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
        })
      })
      setComments(newComments)
   })
```

When the user creates a new comments, I set a loading state and disable the comment section

```js
// React hook
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
// Add comment
const addComment = () => {
   const comment = {text:"hello"}
   setSaving(true)
   db.collection(`users/${postUid}/posts/${postId}/comments`).doc()
      .set(comment)
      .then(()=>{
         setSaving(false)
      })
}
```

My problem is (a good problem to have), the subscription `onSnapshot` gets the new comment before my `addComment` callback is completed, creating some visual issues: 
- Makes the app look buggy when the comment input is still loading but the comment already there
- If there is an error (ex: database permission issue), the comment shows up in the list and then disappears...

Any idea what I can change to not have the `onSnapshot` update before the create is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) in the doc:

> Local writes in your app will invoke snapshot listeners immediately.
>   This is because of an important feature called "latency compensation."
>   When you perform a write, your listeners will be notified with the new
>   data before the data is sent to the backend.
>
> Retrieved documents have a `metadata.hasPendingWrites` property that
>   indicates whether the document has local changes that haven't been
>   written to the backend yet.

See also the following remark in the "Listen to multiple documents in a collection" [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection):

> As explained above under Events for local changes, you will receive
>   events immediately for your local writes. Your listener can use the
>   `metadata.hasPendingWrites` field on each document to determine whether
>   the document has local changes that have not yet been written to the
>   backend.

So you can use this property to display the change only if it has been written to the back-end, something along the following lines (untested):

```
db.collection(`users/${userId}/posts/${postId}/comments`)
   .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      let newComments = []
      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        if (!doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
           newComments.push({
               id: doc.id,
               ...doc.data()
           })
        }
      })
      setComments(newComments)
   })
```